# Data annotations do not work for custom model

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I read and set it to list of model with the code below, My issue is that although I have defined data annotation attributes for my model(city) it's not work.

For example here is 3 lines of csv file:

```
CityName    CityCode    DistrictName    ZipCode
Adana   121 Alada?  1720
Adana   1   Ceyhan  1920
Adana   1   Ceyhan  1930
```

I expect exception occurs in first line because city code is "121" which must be between 1-81. I also tried ModelState.IsValid; it always returns true for my case. How can I guarantee that this field is in valid range?

```
public List<City> readFileToList(string filename, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] queryparams)
{
    string fullName = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data", filename);
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullName);
    List<City> cities = lines.Skip(1).Select(l => new City
    {
        name = l.Split(',')[0],
        cityCode = Convert.ToInt32(l.Split(',')[1]),
        district = l.Split(',')[2],
        zipCode = l.Split(',')[3],
    }).ToList();
    return cities;
}
```

and here is the model definition:

```
public class City
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0,81)]
        public int cityCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60)]
        public string district { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 99999)]
        public string zipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code to see weather your class is valid or now. You can write something like this :

```
public bool ValidateCity(City city,out List<ValidationResult> results)    
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(city);
    results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    return Validator.TryValidateObject(city, context, results, true);
}
```

You can throw exception if this method is true and also see why your model is not valid in results